# xmllint Search value of a tag based on tag name in xml document

Tags: xml, xmllint

I am trying to pull a value out of an xml document using xmllint. but the way xml is structured is following.

```
    <configuration> 
    <property>
    <name>hive.exec.reducers.max</name>
    <value>999</value>

    <description>max number of reducers will be used. If the one
        specified in the configuration parameter mapred.reduce.tasks is
        negative, hive will use this one as the max number of reducers when
        automatically determine number of reducers.</description>


      </property>

  <property>

    <name>hive.cli.print.header</name>
    <value>false</value>

    <description>Whether to print the names of the columns in query output.</description>


  </property>
  <property>

<name>hive.cli.print.current.db</name>

    <value>false</value>

    <description>Whether to include the current database in the hive prompt.</description>


  </property>
</configuration>
```

Lets say, I want to pull the value of hive.cli.print.current.db, the output should be "false". How xmllint can be used to pull the value from a given name tag in a xml document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following xpath query should work.

`xmllint --xpath "//property[name[text()='hive.cli.print.current.db']]/value/text()" file.xml`

Translation:

Find property element that contains child node (name) with given text and return text contained in another (value) child node.

Comment: Hello Sir, is there any other way to do this but without xpath, since the version installed of xmllint does not offer xpath as one of the available options. and since I need to run a cluster wide script, I don't think the upgrade request will be fullfilled just because I said so.... Thank you :-)

Comment: You can try something like: `echo "cat //property[name[text()='hive.cli.print.current.db']]/value" | xmllint --shell file.xml`, which will have some extra output, but you can remove/filter that using `sed` or `grep` easily.